# Need help regarding electromagnetic suspension implementation

Tags: arduino, motor, electronics, actuator, automation

I an trying to implement an electromagnetic suspension system on model/small scale (like the bose suspension system in this video: https://youtu.be/3KPYIaks1UY). Upon doing some research on this topic, I found out that linear electromagnetic motors are used for this system. But I am unable to find any actuators for small scale usage. Does anyone know which components I can use for this project? Or can I just use normal electromagnets and control them with a microcontroller (Is this possible ?) If not, what alternatives do you suggest for this project ? Before implementing a full 4 wheel car model, I just want to make a single wheel model first before moving ahead. Please help !

Comment: a speaker contains a linear motor

Comment: @jsotola Oh, can you provide more information ? Like, will it be useful for this project ?

Comment: my comment is meant to point you to a real world example of a linear actuator that is magnetically driven